# Split a string using regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this problem in out project

```
$line = substr($line,8);
$LIT_YARN = '".*"';
$VAR_NAME = '[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*';
$TEMP2 = "/($LIT_YARN|$VAR_NAME)/";

$line = trim($line);
preg_match_all($TEMP2,$line,$params);

var_dump($params[0]);
```

the simple input is

```
" "askdj" "asjdk" "asdasndw" "
```

the complicated input is

```
" "asd" Y "asd" X "
```

variables can also be inputted

simple input resulted to a single string

```
params[0] => "askdj" "asjdk" "asdasndw"
```

I was expecting like this

```
params[0] => "askdj"
params[1] => "asjdk"
params[2] => "asdasndw"
```

complicated input should result to

```
params[0] => "asd"
params[1] => 'Y'
params[2] => "asd"
params[3] => 'X'
```

including the X and Y which are variables

how should i do the trick?

Comment: cant design a regex without input string, do i assume its `"askdj asjdk asdasndw"`, give a couple of examples if you can

Comment: $params[0] is an array of strings. check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Not sure what your input string is, but if it's as mentioned by @gwillie, then that worked for me: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "askdj" [1]=> string(5) "asjdk" [2]=> string(8) "asdasndw" } `

Comment: @gwillie 

the input string is " "askdj" "asjdk" "asdasndw" "

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox " "askdj" "asjdk" "asdasndw" " was the input

Comment: well in that case dont bother with regex, just use `explode(' ', $string)`, as it seems you are spliting by a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`preg_match_all('/"([A-Za-z0-9]+)"/', '" "askdj" "asjdk" "asdasndw" "', $Matches))`

You want to match a quote, then at least one alphanumeric character, then an ending quote. Put the alphanumeric characters in parentheses to capture the output and put it in `$Matches`.

Comment: i have edited the question, there is another input which includes the variables as parameters.. i have answered the question... ill post it at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

what is your variable $line value?

maybe you can var_dump($params) see its result, in regular expessions $params[o

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/\"([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)\"|([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)/", '" "askdj" "asjdk" "asdasndw" "', $Matches))
```

so this will accept Literal Strings and String Variables.... Big THanks for @Zach Rattner's Answer..